# AutoLogin in FB.login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i need to know if it's possible that the function FB.login in javascript SDK for facebook, could make autologin without promt the dialog.
I think that i would need some permission but anyone works me.
If anyone knows i would apreciatte it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

you mean, if user of your website has FB account and is already logged in, then you do not want to show him Login dialog, right? Then take a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/

> The example below implements the following features:
>
> ...
>
> 2 - init's the SDK with **status: true** to enable the checking of the user's
>   authentication status at init-time

that means if user is logged in already, then

> FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response)

will be called before login dialog will be displayed.

Comment: Thx for the info. My problem is that my app want to get information of an user, but i need to call login function and if the user is not logged, the program show a popup with login form. I want to know if it's possible that the user confirm my app and then i have access to his data althought he aren't connected.

Comment: of course it's not possible. Everything should be done in the context of the LOGGED IN user.